# how to serialize a class implements two interfaces who have same based interface

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am trying use protobuf v2 to serialize a class A implements interfaces B and C. And both B and C derived from D.

---

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
[ProtoBuf.Includes(101, typeof(B))
[ProtoBuf.Includes(101, typeof(C))
interface D{...}
```

---

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
[ProtoBuf.Includes(101, typeof(A))
interface B:interfae D{...}
```

---

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
[ProtoBuf.Includes(101, typeof(A))
interface C:interface D
{
   ...
}
```

---

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
class A: interface B, interface C{...}
```

There will return error: a type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces are not really the same kind of "derived" (inheritance) as *class* inheritance. While *basic* interface support is provided, this is not a scenario that protobuf-net currently supports.

As to whether it *could* support it - that would take some thought. I would suggest [logging a request, here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/entry?template=Defect%20report%20from%20user).

Comment: @enzhou.liu to repeat... " this is not a scenario that protobuf-net currently supports.

As to whether it could support it - that would take some thought.". No easy mechanism to do this leaps to mind; it is essentially the diamond problem.

Comment: @MarcGravell are types that inherit from 2 different interfaces still unsupported? or was there some breakthrough?

Comment: I have a similar problem with a `class C : IA, IB` and two properties of type `IA` and `IB`. Why is this not supported? When you serialize or deserialize you know whether to look at the type table for `IA` or `IB` based on the type of the property. Also, I used `model.Add(typeof(IA), true).AddSubType(101, typeof(C));` and `model.Add(typeof(IB), true).AddSubType(101, typeof(C));` so I wonder if it even matters what the property type is, given that the stored numeric code would be the same either way... then again I don't know the fine details of protobuf-net's design.

Comment: @Qwertie The answer to "Why is this not supported?" is always one of two options; a) "nobody has yet taken the time to fully consider the consequences of that, design it, implement it, and test it", or b) "somebody *has* taken the time to do that, and has found that it is inherently problematic"; I can't tell you which one of those it is without stressing my memory, but this is *not* a trivial scenario

Comment: Even though it sounds trivial.