# Proto-buf .NET Serialization of complex inheritance interfaces

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I would like to serialize for classes which do implement several interfaces some inheriting from the same base interface. Currently i use the BinaryFormatter, but i would love to use proto-buf .NET. But i think currently i would face issues similar to this described problem:
[how to serialize a class implements two interfaces who have same based interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639934/how-to-serialize-a-class-implements-two-interfaces-who-have-same-based-interface)

The only possible solution i currently think of would be a wrapper around my classes which serializes a simpler data class which i use to create my complex classes.

Let me try to explain it further, like in the cited example i have a structure like this:

```
public interface IProduct
{ 
    string SomeMethod(); 
}

public interface ISimpleProduct : IProduct
{ 
    int SomeProperty { get; } 
}

public interface IConstructionProduct : IProduct
{
    int AnotherProperty {get; 
}

public class ConcreteProduct : ISimpleProduct , IConstructionProduct
{
     int SomeProperty {get; set;}
     int AnotherProperty {get; set;}

     string SomeMethod()
     {
           return "A concrete Product";
     }
}
```

Now i wish to serialize ConcreteProduct, as i thought this is not possible currently in proto-buf .net i was considering to have a wrapper data class, like this:

```
public class ProductData
{
    int[] PropertyValues { get; set;}
}
```

and to add to the IProductInterface a method to build each concrete product, like

```
public interface IProduct
{
      string SomeMethod();
      IProduct BuildProduct(ProductData data);
      ProductData ToData();
}
```

Of course ProductData would be more sophisticated in reality but just for the concept. I would serialize now ProductData. I would not like to change the interface setup in the Product ConcreteProduct class as these interfaces are needed for further stuff later on. What i like about this approach, that issues with extensions could be dealt with in the BuildProduct implementations.
And again, i am a newbie, so if anything is just plain nonsense, sorry for that and correct me.

@ Marc, i know you are author, thx a lot for that stuff, but more for other posts (i am not using proto-buf yet though) for example on DataTable stuff, already your post about the autogenerate columns saved a lot of time for me.

Comment: Can you give an example of the sort of model you'd want to serialize, so I can give an accurate answer? (author, protobuf-net)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you're going for the [union types](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html#union) approach. You want to make a single serialization format that fits all your products. Additionally, you want each of your products to map to that union type and map back.

So you're remaining concern is on how to do the mapping. Honestly, I don't think you'll be happy in the long run with these two methods in the IProduct interface. And I hope you're aware that you need to deal with the problem of deserialization: Which type do you actually instantiate? Let me put it this way: With your code, you'll have to call new ConcreteProduct().BuildProduct(data) to get your ConcreteProduct. And the question is: How do you know it's a ConcreteProduct that you have to instantiate? The code that wants to call BuildProduct needs to know this! You could cut those methods and create a separate infrastructure for your mapping tasks. Here's what a factory method pattern would look like for this kind of problem:

```
public interface IProductMapper {
  IProduct Unmap(ProductData data);
  ProductData Map(IProduct product);
}

public static class ProductMapperFactory {
  public static IProductMapper GetMapper(ProductData data) {
    if (data.Type == "ConcreteProduct") return new ConcreteProductMapper();
    else if ...
  }

  public static IProductMapper GetMapper(IProduct product) {
    if (product is ConcreteProduct) return new ConcreteProductMapper();
    else if ...
  }
}

public class ConcreteProductMapper : IProductMapper {
  public IProduct Unmap(ProductData data) {
    var product = new ConcreteProduct();
    // map properties
    return product;
  }

  public ProductData Map(IProduct data) {
    var data = new ProductData();
    // map data
    return data;
  }
}
```

You see, the crucial line is `data.Type == "ConcreteProduct"`: Somehow you must specify the kind of product in the data in order to know which kind of product to instantiate when mapping back from the union type.

Another difficulty that I see with union types in general is de/serialization of object graphs. Since you have your own serialization types, you need to write your own code to de/compose object graphs. If you're a newbie as you say, that'll probably put you into a world of hurt (or world of learning if you prefer :-p).

In any case, does it really need to be interfaces that you want to de/serialize? Would it be possible to instead create a class hierarchy where you're starting from a `Product` base class from which all other products derive and which carries the necessary includes. I assume this would create less troubles (with protobuf at least).

And finally, the master question: Why do you want to switch from the BinaryFormatter to protobuf exactly?