# How to declare that a type is implementing an interface and a base class in ProtoBuf?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We have one case in our model that looks like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public interface ISomeInterface{
    //...
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100,typeof(SomeImplementation)]
public class SomeRootClass {
    //...
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SomeImplementation: SomeRootClass,ISomeInterface{
    //...
}
```

At some point, we have an instance of `SomeImplementation` that is reference in a class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeClassWithInterfaceUsage{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ISomeInterface SomeReference{get;set;}
}
```

When we try to serialize, we have this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : It was not possible to prepare a
>   serializer for: SomeRootClass   ----> System.InvalidOperationException
>   : No serializer defined for type: ISomeInterface

So I changed the interface to look like:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100,typeof(SomeImplementation)]
public interface ISomeInterface{
    //...
}
```

But now I've this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : A type can only participate in one inheritance hierarchy
```

How should I manage this case?

Comment: You really like the complex edge scenarios, don't you :) have you ever considered using a simple DTO model for serialization, rather than trying to force the serializer to work against a complex model that isn't a great fit?

Comment: Well, it's the issues I'm encountering right now with out current model (which is not a DTO). I would have gone to the DTO path if it wouldn't mean to duplicate and think about the 500 classes of our current model. It would be a nightmare to maintain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not supported, check Marks answer here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7640233/2243584)

I did end up declaring only the type and using objects for the properties with the DynamicType flag on the ProtoMemberAttribute

Comment: I endorse this answer.